# Recursive procedure for sum of squares of first n odd numbers?

Tags: racket

I'm trying to implement recursive procedure for sum of squares of first n odd numbers on Racket
(starting with 1)
e.g., (sum-alt-squares-recursive 0) is 0
(sum-alt-squares-recursive 1) is 1 (1^2)
(sum-alt-squares-recursive 2) is 10 (3^2 + 1^2)
(sum-alt-squares-recursive 3) is 35 (5^2 + 3^2 + 1^2)

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow works to solve specific problems, eg: "I tried to X using Y but Z happened instead. Where did I go wrong?" We need more from you in order to help.

Comment: `(define (sum-alt-squares n) (* 1/3 n (sub1 (* 4 n n))))` (thanks, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_i%3D1%5En+%282i-1%29%5E2)!)

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive procedure that uses a linear iterative process

```
(define (sum-alt-squares-recursive x (y 1) (z 0))
  (if (zero? x)
      z                                        ; if x is zero, return accumulator z
      (sum-alt-squares-recursive (- x 1)       ; x goes down by 1 each iteration
                                 (+ y 2)       ; y starts at 1 and goes up by 2 each iteration
                                 (+ z (* y y)) ; z, goes up by y^2 each time
      )))

(sum-alt-squares-recursive 1) ; => 1
(sum-alt-squares-recursive 2) ; => 10
(sum-alt-squares-recursive 3) ; => 35
```